# How to make an Icon-Bubble Chart where size of icons depends upon size?

Tags: jquery, css, charts, jquery-plugins

Looking for a known library, plugin, or implementation of Icon-Bubble Chart similar to bubble chart as given on this [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9TGp.png) but will contain circular icons instead of plain bubbles. Somewhat like the following image.

[image]

Source data would be something like the following:

```
[{
  Twitter: 9212,
  Facebook: 3503,
  Blog: 2483,
  YouTube: 3000,
  Instagram: 2100
}]
```

Size of the bubbles should be in proportion to weightage. Looking to write a jQuery plugin for this but some reference or research that can save some time could be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to use `size` as a term for both their on-screen visual dimension and their initial `value`, let's call them `size` (the visual one) and `weight` (their respective number).

It's fairly easy to determine the radius based on current weight (actually, the radius **can** be the weight, as long as you scale the entire result down/up to match the available space, after you're done drawing).

Once you determined their radius  (size), you can go ahead and draw the first one. It doesn't really matter where you draw it because you'll reposition the entire composition later on, based on resulting viewport.

You'll also need a preferred angle at which to draw the second one (probably -60deg). Another parameter to set is the distance between circles, which you probably want constant. `10%` of the largest one's size seems good but you can always come back and adjust it if needed. With all of the above and the coords of first center, you can determine the coords of second center.

Probably the most challenging part is to determine the coords of the third center when you have first two and the length of each side of resulting triangle. But it's [only trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1989113).

Using the same technique, you can determine each of the subsequent centers. You can determine center 4 from center 1 and 3, center 5 from 1 and 4 and so on. For your algorithm to be perfect, you'd need a way to determine when you no longer have to use center 1 + last one added, but a different center (when the snail of circles made a full circle and using C1 would cause overlap with circle 2 - it would be trickier and it would involve keeping track of the angle - however, for your case, this calculation is not necessary).
However, if you do need this (for creating snails), you'll want a method that checks for overlapping, like this:

- try to determine next circle using centers of first and last
- if resulting circle's center is closer to any other center than the sum of their radiuses plus the gap, you're overlapping, try to use 2nd and last...
- keep going until you have no overlapping

When you're done, all you need to do is to determine the size of the entire resulting drawing, so you can correctly position and size it in the available space.
Which is fairly easy (you calculate top, left, bottom and right for each circle from their center positions and radiuses) and feed them to some lots (arrays - left points values, rights points values, tops and bottoms). The lowest of lefts, lowest of bottoms, highest of rights and highest of tops determine your viewbox, at which point you have the width and the height, so you can resize and position the entire composition in the parent.

It would take an experienced software developer ~1hr to write all of the above. Currently, your biggest problem is you didn't write down the logical steps of the routine and you didn't write code for any one of those steps.

I believe my answer will help out with the logical steps and I suggest you write the the part you actually know how to solve, and leave out the bits you don't (if any). At which point you'd be able to ask a much more pertinent and well received question on SO, one which a lot of people would probably answer or help with.

---

**Edit** Your question came back nagging me (it's the type of problem I enjoy solving). I therefore used it as an excuse to take Vue.js for a spin, which is something I wanted to do for some time now. Here's [the result](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/xsLjb5of/).
**Note**: It doesn't have the check for overlap method I talked about above (it simply rotates around first circle) and chances are I won't code it. I admit I never liked trigonometry much. :)

Comment: @ChaosLegion you'll get this response from [so] whenever you ask a question without laying out the research effort you have put in. Even listing links to similar questions which did not help, specifying why they didn't, is useful for anyone considering an answer. Ideally, you should also post some code attempting to solve your current issue. In the end, you could say SO requires proof it's a programmer who asks the question, not the client needing a programmer. If we answered client questions here we'd do ourselves a big disservice.

Comment: @Chaos, see the lil' edit I added to my question. Use it as an inspiration (to maybe draw some absolutely positioned divs holding your icons?) but, please, don't ask me to modify it for your purposes. Coding it served my own personal purpose and that was my only motivation. I hope you don't mind my position on this.

Comment: Oh, and I was quite wrong in my estimation. It didn't take me 1hr, it took me about 2 days (the trigonometry part was roughly 4hrs - the rest was figuring out `vue.js`).

Comment: Thanks. It took me 5 hours without vue.js, by just position all circular div tags instead of rendering svg. But I dig your approach. :)